Mixed models: equivalence between residual covariance structure and random effects?
Is there a way to specify the covariance structure of a within-subject repeated measures model (MMRM with no random effects) such that the model is mathematically equivalent to a mixed model with either 1) random intercepts or 2) random intercepts and slopes? If there is no equivalence, can the MMRM be specified to match the mixed models at least in terms of the estimated CIs for the fixed effects? I'm interested in both discrete time with a) set measurement time points (can use unstructured covariance matrix) and b) continuous time where subjects aren't measured at defined time points (can't use unstructured covariance matrix). So I'm looking for four covariance structures total (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b).
I found this question to be related but I'm still not sure about the answer.

Under (restricted) maximum likelihood estimation, you never fit a linear mixed-effects model in reality. You fit the implied marginal model with the variance-covariance matrix $V_i$ formulated in the cited answer.

@DimitrisRizopoulos Thanks! In that case, would it be sensible to rephrase the question to ask which within-subject residual error covariance structures best match the implied marginal models for random intercepts and random intercepts+slopes?

The point is that you have an exact match. When you have random intercepts alone, then the implied covariance structure is compound symmetry. When you have random intercepts & random slopes, then the error terms of the corresponding marginal model have the covariance matrix $V_i = Z D Z^\top + \sigma^2 I$, where $Z$ is a two column-matrix with the first column equal to 1, and the second equal to the time variable, and $D$ is the covariance matrix of the random effects.

Thanks again, I think I am closer to understanding... For the random intercepts & slopes case, is there an "implied covariance structure" that corresponds to one of the "standard" structures used in MMRMs? (I hesitate to say "standard", basically I mean something I would find implemented in an R package like nlme or mmrm).

As far as I know, no.
